# Do not escape backslashes in formulas with rmarkdown/md_document

Tags: r, r-markdown

For use with grav CMS, I want to create md-files from .rmd. The settings below double the backslashes in the formula, but I need the formula untouched. Any suggestion what pandoc option to use?

```
---
output:
md_document
---
# This is an rmd file

$\alpha = \frac{4}{3}$
```

This is a repost of a question on http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html after 20 days

Comment: maybe try ``output:
  md_document:
    mathjax:  default``

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, I just tried that with the OP's example but still got double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try the markdown variants like:

```
---
output:
    md_document:
        variant: markdown_github
---
# This is an rmd file

$\alpha = \frac{4}{3}$
```

Maybe take a closer look at http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/markdown_document_format.html

Comment: github does not allow for formulae